# how Uploading Image to cloudnary on Cpanel Hosted Node + express project?

Tags: express, multer, cloudinary

I have A simple blog website developed in express and i am using cloudinary for  hosting my project. Everything works fine on local environment but on cpanel the images are not uploaded to clouinary. On submiting the form it keeps on roating.

My Code looks like this

1. Route

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const uploader = require("./../../util/multer");
//middleware calling
const cloudUploaderMiddleware = require("./../../middleware/cloudUploader") 
//controller call
const advertismentController = require('../../controller/admin/advertisment')


router.post('/add-advertisment', uploader.single("image"), cloudUploaderMiddleware, advertismentController.postAdvertisment)


module.exports = router
```

2. Util/multer.js

```
const multer = require('multer');

module.exports = multer({
  storage: multer.diskStorage({}),
  limits: { fileSize: 5000000 }
});
```

3. cloudUploader.js

```
const cloudinary = require("./../config/cloudnaryConfig");

const cloudUploader = async (req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.file) {
        console.log("uploaded without imgae")
        next();
    } else {
        console.log("uploaded imgae")
        const upload = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.file.path);
        req.cloudLink = upload.secure_url
        next()
    }

}

module.exports = cloudUploader
```

4. cloudinaryConfig.js

```
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary');

cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
  api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET
});

module.exports = cloudinary;
```

Please help me to fix this issue. I cant use other hosting provider because they are costly and cpanel is cheap. Thats what my client has demanded. Thank you in advance

Comment: Any errors in your server-side logs? Do you see any of your `console.log` statements (`uploaded imgae`)? Does the file upload to Cloudinary if you check your account? Does `upload` contain any error/successful response from Cloudinary?